how can I find what objects reference a custom property?
I am animating a figure.  The rig has over 200 "drivers" which point to custom properties on the armature.   I cannot figure out how to trace the custom properties into the armature itself.   For example, a (example) custom property "XyzAbc" is located in the "Custom Properties" section of the Armature object, but how do I find out which one of the 548 bones in the rig is using the custom property "XyzAbc"?   There is a section in Armature outline called "Drivers" but it contains, as far as I can tell, nothing useful - it cannot be clicked into, has no properties, and shows names or other information.


After some investigation and a lot of typing, it looks like this:
bpy.data contains a collection "actions"  (bpy.data.actions)
    Actions collection contains Action objects
        Each Action object contains collection "Fcurves"  action.fcurves
            Fcurves collection contains Fcurve objects
                Each Fcurve may (or may not) contain a Driver property

And that's where the drivers live.
